# SonarQube Bulk Change - failed to assign assignee

Tags: sonarqube

I just upgraded SonarQube from version 6.7 to 7.1 and realise the bulk change unable to pick up assignee from the assignee's drop-down list.

[image]

When I tried to look into service that did bulk change, found out that the assignee was empty. Please refer to the screenshot below:

[image]

System information

Login: via LDAP

Database: MS SQL Server

Is there any walkaround for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like bug in SonarQube: https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-10862

> The bug exists in 7.1 but has been fixed already in 7.2.

Comment: Thanks. Just have to wait for the release.